# Auto image enhance for Ubuntu

Tags: linux, photos, image-editing

F-Spot had an "enhance" button that magically turns the image on the left into the image next to it (see below). It worked brilliantly for quite a range of images. Unfortunately it has problems, and I'm not using it for photo management any more.

Does anyone know of a similar excellent "enhance" function? The one in Shotwell is useless.

[image]

Comment: Related: [StackOverflow: How do I do the equivalent of Gimp's Colors, Auto, White Balance in Python-Fu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48268068/how-do-i-do-the-equivalent-of-gimps-colors-auto-white-balance-in-python-fu).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you use the GIMP, the toolbar menu has an option for Colours->Auto->Equalize. I tried it on your "before" image and the "after" result was almost identical.

Also GIMP would give you more control over adjusting colour curves/contrast/etc. manually if you prefer.

Comment: You're right! It does better than ImageMagick on the top half, but still slightly worse than the f-spot version. I'm sure it's possible to improve that manually, if you know how.

Comment: +1 I think The GIMP does better than ImageMagick in this case, and far better in general. Sometimes I find Colours->Auto->White Balance helps too.

Comment: Can you figure out how to run this (GIMP's auto equalize) from the command-line? Here's a resource I found to get started: https://www.gimp.org/tutorials/Basic_Batch/.

Answer (score 27):

If you are on the command line I recommend "convert", a command from the ImageMagick Package. Try:

```
$ convert -enhance -equalize -contrast image.jpg image_enhanced.jpg
```

And to loop a whole batch in Bash shell:

```
for file in *.jpg; do
 convert -enhance -equalize -contrast $file "${file%.jpg}_new.jpg"
done
```

[image: snapshot_batch]

Comment: Hey, that's not bad at all! The bottom half of the image comes out better, in my opinion. But the top half of the image comes out worse :-p  I'll update the answer to show all three.

Comment: '-equalize' didn't work well for me, but other options are worth to try.

Comment: Produces so so so so soooo ugly output. It looks like I just looked at the image through a dark coke bottle at night, with a flashlight.

Answer (score 22):

Just for people that stumble over this thread and think, the results with enhance, equalize and/or contrast are ugly should definitely try this options:

```
convert -auto-gamma -auto-level -normalize original.jpg improved.jpg
```

And for the batch-lovers, having the originals in the `orig`-folder...:

```
for sp in orig/*; do 
  echo "Converting Image: $sp"
  convert -auto-gamma -auto-level -normalize $sp $(basename $sp)
done
```

I believe, the result is exactly what people want and need for their photos: White balance, gamma correction and overall light correction...

Have fun!

Comment: Worked great. **NOTE** the `bash` code modifies the images in-place, add a prefix to `$sp` if you want to retain the originals.

Comment: Images are not converted in-place with the script. Original images are in "orig" folder and converted will be created in the current folder.

Comment: Visually, I cannot tell a difference between the original answer and this for the sample images I have.

Comment: For photos, I see great differences. The original answer show very unnatural images for me. My options simply enhance the images like GIMP does for auto correction.

Answer (score 2):

When trying to enhance the visibility of details in an image where some regions are low-contrast, I found none of the single-step solutions in ImageMagick or The GIMP satisfactory.  (XV used to have a great button, but is non-free and hard to obtain now.)

But the following process produced the kind of results I wanted.  It simulates a high/medium pass filter in The GIMP.

http://www.gimpusers.com/tutorials/equalize-homogenize-brightness

1. Do Layer -> Duplicate Layer
2. In the Layers Window (Ctrl-L) be sure the upper copy is selected
3. Do Filter -> Blur -> Gaussian Blur with a medium size radius (e.g. 25)
4. Do Colors -> Invert
5. Do Colors -> Desaturate -> (Lightness)
6. In the Layers Window (Ctrl-L) set the Mode to "Overlay"
7. If satisfied, do Image -> Flatten Image.  Otherwise undo to step 2 and try again with a different blur radius.

You may see a visible "halo" around dark elements, or "shadow" around light elements - that is it working!

Better results might be obtained by combining a number of layers with different blur radii.